# React DOM not updating even though the state and props have

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom, react-state-management

I am looking to use map() to iterate over and add to my DOM in react, however, my DOM is not updating.

I think the everything is syntactically written ok, so I am really stumped by this. Any help you can give me I'd really appreciate, thanks.

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
...
    searchThis() {
        axios.get("/getYoutube", {params: {searchString: this.state.searchVal}}).then(({ data }) => {
            this.setState({
                youtubeVids: data.resp.items
            })
        })
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.youtubeVids.length > 0) {
            console.log(this.state.youtubeVids[0].snippet.thumbnails.default.url)

            return (
                <div className="app-container">
                    <div className="app-header">
                        <h1>YouTube API App</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className="app-body">
                        <div className="each-body-section">
                            <SearchResults 
                                youtubeVids = {this.state.youtubeVids}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default App;
```

Right now I am bringing server api results into the frontend using `setState()` and Axios through the `searchThis()` method, which I am logging and seeing successfully in my console from my `props`. However in SearchResults.js, nothing is updating in the DOM
SearchResults.js

```
import React from "react";

const SearchResults = props => {
    console.log("props in search ", props.youtubeVids)

    return (
    <div className="each-body-section video-container">
            {props.youtubeVids.map((video) => {
                <div key={video.id.videoId}>
                    <div className="video-title">
                        <h2>{video.snippet.title} </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src={video.snippet.thumbnails.high.url} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>{video.snippet.description}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            })}
    </div>
    )
}

export default SearchResults
```

Comment: What do you get if you put a console log inside the map for example:

{props.youtubeVids.map((video) => {
 console.log("video", video)
      return (
                <div key={video.id.videoId}>
...rest of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, its because you are trying to map an empty array in SearchResults.js

Change SearchResults.js to the code below and try again:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SearchResults extends Component {

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.youtubeVids);
        if (this.props.youtubeVids.length > 0) {
            var youtubeVidsMap = this.props.youtubeVids.map((video) => <div key={video.id.videoId}>
                <div className="video-title">
                    <h2>{video.snippet.title} </h2>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src={video.snippet.thumbnails.high.url} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>{video.snippet.description}</p>
                </div>
            </div>);

        }
        return (

            <div className="each-body-section video-container">
                {youtubeVidsMap}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SearchResults;
```

If you want to use stateless component, the code below should work:

```
import React from "react";

const SearchResults = props => {

    if (props.youtubeVids.length > 0) {
        var youtubeVidsMap = props.youtubeVids.map((video) => <div key={video.videoId}>
            <div className="video-title">
                <h2>{video.snippet.title} </h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src={video.snippet.thumbnails.high.url} />
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>{video.snippet.description}</p>
            </div>
        </div>);

    }

    return (
    <div className="each-body-section video-container">
            {youtubeVidsMap}
    </div>
    )
}

export default SearchResults
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, but this component doesn't need state so ```class SearchResults extends Component``` is not what I am looking for here and therefore I don't need the ```render()``` method either. The ```console.log(props.youtubeVids);``` (I don't need the ```this``` keyword context without state) is showing in my dev console that there is an array there, so I'm not sure why you think it's empty.

Comment: Its empty because the axios get call is async so the initial array available is empty. You have to wait for the array to get data so that you can map into it.

Comment: I will add stateless component code as well to the answer. I hope that helps.

Comment: Ahhhhh. Getcha. Thanks for the updated answer, makes total sense.